# Deserilization an object in web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a serialized object in C# .net 4 which contains some images and strings.

What I want is send that object to web browser and deserialize it in client's web browser.

What are the technologies that I will need? Is is possible to do this? My requirement is to save a class with images and few strings to hard disk and use it back.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking. What are you trying to accomplish? Be specific. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have a few images and i loaded them in to bitmap array and i serialized that object using c#.net serialization. From that onward i don't want use that images and i want use that object which saves in my hard disk.(like create a new data type which contain a few images). in desktop it is ok. i can save object and can read back. what i want is if client browser ask that object then send it to client from asp.net web server and deserialize object in client browser and display that images.i try to create browser plugin using firebreath and i was not able to do that using that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to serialize an object from server to browser. Googling for "JSON C#" will certainly give you a handful of resources and examples to transform a C# object into a JSON string.

But serializing an image won't be very helpful: what would the browser do with such a binary image. Images are displayed in a  web page thanks to a URL pointing to an image stored on a web server.

And, until HTML5 is finalized and well supported by browsers, JavaScript won't be able to store anything on the hard drive.